# Unable to connect cloudbuild to compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-sdk

I want to execute a script which is in my compute engine using cloudbuild but somehow cloudbuild is not able to ssh into my vm , in my vm "OS LOGIN" is enabled and also have only internal ip.

here is my cloudbuild.yaml file

> steps:
>
> - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'   id: Update staging server   entrypoint: /bin/sh   args:
>
>   - '-c'
>   - |
>     set -x && 
>     gcloud compute ssh vm_name --zone=us-central1-c --command='/bin/sh /pullscripts/pull.sh'

I am attaching my error pics

[cloudbuild error page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoTHS.jpg)

[cloudbuild error page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPBrJ.jpg)

Also my question is , is it possible connect a vm using cloud sdk if "os login" is enabled.

Comment: Please do not add error messages as images. Instead copy the error as text with the relevant information

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably have to add the `roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor` role to the cloudbuild service account. Please read [this](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/faq) Google documentation, which shows you what to do with a certain error code.

**Error code 4033**

Either you don't have permission to access the instance, the instance doesn't exist, or the instance is stopped.

Comment: but we havent implemented the IAP service to connect our vm , we connect our vm using vpn and os login.

Comment: @dantealighieri I'd suggest to re-read the documentation for the products you're using to fully understand this since what nebulastic mentions is correct. Cloud Build uses workers with Public IPs and since your VM only has a private IP it needs to connect using IAP tunneling and in order to do this the Cloud Build SA needs the permissions to use this tunnel  `roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor`

Comment: Another approach will be using a private pool https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/private-pools/private-pools-overview

Comment: Also please read https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding

Answer (score 0):

in fact, you can use gcloudbuild to connect in any vm, just need a docker configuration and upload the files (private_key, scripts, etc). I've this repo to solve this problem: https://github.com/jmbl1685/gcloudbuild-vm-ssh-connect

I hope that the above help you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `--internal-ip` which looks like as follows:

```
gcloud compute ssh vm_name --zone=us-central1-c --internal-ip
```